# Modern Modelling Formats that Support Vertex Buffers

Tags: opengl, modeling, vertex-buffer-objects

Are there any modeling formats that directly support Vertex Buffer Objects?

Currently my game engine has been using [Wavefront Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510999/how-to-create-a-vertex-buffer-object-from-wavefront-data), but I have always been using them with immediate mode and display lists. This works, but I wanted to upgrade my entire system to modern OpenGL, including Shaders. I know that I can use immediate mode and display lists with Shaders, but like most aspiring developers, I want my game to be the best it can be. After asking the question linked above, I quickly came to the realization that Wavefront Models simply don't support Vertex Buffers; this is mainly due to the fact of how the model is indexed. In order for a Vertex Buffer Object to be used, Vertices, Texture Coordinates, and the Normal arrays all need to be equal in length.

I can achieve this by writing my own converter, which I have done. Essentially I unroll the indexing and create the associated arrays. I don't even need to exactly use `glDrawElements` then, I can just use `glDrawArrays`, which I'm perfectly fine doing. The only problem is that I am actually duplicating data; the arrays become massive(especially with large models), and this just seems wrong to me. Certainly there has to be a modern way of initializing a model into a Vertex Buffer without completely unrolling the indexing. So I have two questions.

**1. Are their any modern model formats/concepts that support direct Vertex Buffer Objects?**

**2. Is this already an industry standard? Do most game engines unroll the indexing(and inflate the arrays also called *unpacking*) at runtime to create the game world assets?**

Comment: Care to explain the vote to close? Or how this is "Primarily Opinion Based"? What about this is opinion based?

Comment: You're asking for a format or library recommendation and opinion on how to do a certain thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary concern with storage formats is space efficiency. Reading from storage media you're limited by I/O bandwidth by large. So any CPU cycles you can invest to reduce the total amount of data to be read from storage will hugely benefit asset loading times. Just to give you the general idea. Even the fastest SSDs you can currently buy at the time of writing this won't get over 5GiB/s (believe me, I tried sourcing something that can saturate 8 lanes of PCIe-3 for my work). Your typical CPU memory bandwidth is at least one order of magnitude above that. GPUs have even more memory bandwidth. Even faster are lower level caches.

So what I'm trying to tell you: That index unrolling overhead? It's mostly an inconvenience for you, the developer, but probably shaves off some time from loading the assets.

*(suggested edit)*: Of course storing numbers in their text representation is not going to help with space efficiency; depending on the choice of base a single digit represents between 3 to 5 bits (lets say 4 bits). That same text character however consumes 8 bits, so you have about 100% overhead there. The lowest hanging fruit this is storing in a binary format.

But why stop there? How about applying *compression* on the data? There are a number of compressed asset formats. But one particularly well developed one is [OpenCTM](http://openctm.sourceforge.net/), although it would make some sense to add one of the recently developed compression algorithms to it. I'm thinking of [Zstandard](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) here, which compresses data ridiculously well and at the same time is obscenely fast at decompression.

Comment: I'm gathering from this "yes, it's currently an industry standard; there is not much more that you can do." This is what I was afraid of, but at least now I know that my current implementation is spot on, so I can stop chasing the end of a rainbow.

Comment: You might want to add that using a text based format will always be inefficient for storing asset data. If you want to reduce I/O bandwidth, then using a binary format is most of the time unavoidable.

Comment: @BDL: If uncompressed, then yes. If however one applies a modern compression scheme, then it's going to be a head to head race. However storing in binary in a directly accessible structure avoids parsing, which is something desirable.

Comment: @Krythic: Actually Khronos (the standardization body that also maintains OpenGL) maintains such a standard: glTF. However OpenCTM predates it. Didn't I tell you, that this is going to be an opinionated topic? https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF